# Why do I use this notation to store shader's source code in a variable in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers

I am reading the *OpenGL Super Bible* 7th edition and in one of the earliest chapters there is an example of shader source code written like this:

```
static const GLchar * vertex_shader_source[] =
{
"#version 450 core                  \n"
"                                   \n"
"void main(void)                    \n"
// ... etc ...
};
```

Why is this code stored in an GLchar *pointer* source *array* variable?

I mean, isn't `GLchar*` alone enough to store a certain number of consecutive bytes? i.e. why not:

```
static const GLchar* source = ...
```

or:

```
static const GLchar source[] = ...
```

Why do we have to use both `*` and `[]`?

I understand `static const`, so that's not a problem BTW.

Comment: because you are initializing the array at the same time with the part between { ... }, so you want compiler to know its an array

Comment: An array of one item that is a pointer, is effectively the same as that pointer. You can detect the difference via `decltype` but such sophistication doesn't seem relevant here. Possibly this array is a convention that supports having more than one pointer in the array.

Comment: There may be multiple vertex shaders in this array, simple as that.